# DaVinci Configurator Error to be resolved

Tags: autosar

[image]I get an below Error from the MCU Module - MCU01803

> Invalid XPath-expression for Attribute "ENABLE" of node
>   "McuDMAMUXandEDMAConfig":(35016) Cannot get a resource file for target
>   PA and derivative BLAHBLAH.

Maybe this is due to module restrictions.

I tried setting up a project from scratch and I am stuck at this point just before generation.

Is there anyone with an experience of setting up a `BSW project` from scratch?

Vector seems to have poor, rather no documentation.

Comment: Why don't you submit a support request?

Comment: The Support Request was placed a couple of months back. Why would I otherwise ask for help?

Comment: And you are 100% certain that the error message has been issued by DaVinci Configurator?

Comment: Yes, I am indeed. Do you need a screen-shot?

Comment: I'd appreciate a screenshot in order to confirm.

Comment: Yes, updated the query with a screenshot.

Comment: According to the screenshot you are using a third-party generator, i.e. you are trying to configure an Eletrobit stack. Maybe the stack does not support the incriminated parameter. Have you checked with the stack vendor?

Comment: I can hardly believe, that vector has rather poor documentation. I always had a rather very positive impression with vector products and documentation. And as @UweHonekamp said, it looks like a failure in the EB Tresos generator problem. From the wording, I expect a NXP MCU (EB as MCAL provider), and Mcu / DMA/EDMA ... DMA is not standardized in AUTOSAR. Maybe you miss the Processor/derivate setting in the ecuconfig/platform

Comment: I think I did not I will check that and get back to you.